# Are there some alternatives (patterns, etc.) to polymorphism in Java and C++?

Tags: java, c++, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

Polymorphism it is a common and widely used OO principle in such languages as Java and C++.But I'm curious can we achieve such functionality  (capability of an action or method to do different things based on the object that it is acting upon) in Java e.g. or C++ without using virtual methods dispatching (CRTP and static polymorphism in C++ not the case - it is too narrow and language specific) but with some more different (even orthogonal) approach or patterns? May be we can use something from functional programming?

Comment: Google double dispatch. Clojure has multimethods.

Comment: Your question is kind of vague.  What do you want to do that C++ and Java can not do?

Comment: when you talk about "polymorphism" are you talking about subtype polymorphism (implementing interfaces) or parametric polymorphism (generics/templates)?

Comment: @andrewcooke I was talking about subtype polymorphism.If you can please give some link to the information where I can read about different implementations of subtype polymorphism.